Build a project on custom AMI in AWS from azure devops
I'm using AzureDevops (SAAS) pipeline and  i need to lunch custom AMI on AWS Instance and compile the source code on this AMI (on aws).
AWS Toolkit for Azure DevOps" extensions keep complaints the tasks that i'm trying are missing although it's installed.
is there away to achieve to start ec2 and build on the server from AzureDevops pipeline?

You can try to login/connection to the the EC2 instance and install/configure the Self-hosted agents on the VM instance.
Then you can use the Self-hosted agents to run the pipeline jobs in Azure DevOps to build source code. If so, all the tasks in pipeline job are run on the VM instance where the Self-hosted agents is installed.
Note:

You can configure the Self-hosted agents to run as service on the VM instance.
You need to keep the VM instance is online so that the agent is online and available for the pipeline. At least, when you run the pipelines, the VM instance should be online.


